# One to Many relations is always null

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa

Given the following SQL model:

```
Two Views
   VIEW PRODUCT
       ID_PROPOSAL
       ID_PRODUCT

   VIEW PERSON
       ID_ENTITY
       ID_PRODUCT
       NAME

JPA
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "Product.getByProposalId",
                query = "SELECT ie "
                        + "FROM Product ie "
                        + "WHERE ie.idProposal = :proposalId ")
}) 
 @Entity
 Table(name = "PRODUCT")
 public classe Product{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_PRODUCT")
    private Long idProduct;

    @Column(name = "ID_PROPOSAL")
    private Long idProposal;

     @OneToMany(mappedBy="product")
     List<Person> persons;

      public List<Person> getPersons() {
        return persons;
      }

      public void setPersons(List<Person> persons) {
        this.persons= persons;
      }

}

 @Entity
 Table(name = "PERSON")
 public classe Person{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_ENTITY")
    private Long idEntity;

    @Column(name = "ID_PRODUCT")
    private Long idProduct;

     @ManyToOne
     @JoinColumn(name = "ID_PRODUCT", insertable = false, updatable = false)
     Product product;

      public List<Person> getPersons() {
        return persons;
      }

      public void setPersons(List<Person> persons) {
        this.persons= persons;
      }

}


 Query query = emanager.createNamedQuery("Product.getByProposalId");
        query.setParameter("propostaId", proposalId);
        return query.getResultList();
```

It returns the correct product results but for each product do not return any Persons , in the log file i can not seen any query to the View Person.
The application server is websphere and the jpa implementation is openjpa1.2.3

Any ideas ?
Thanks in advance 
Best regards

Comment: So, if you call `product.getPersons().size()` on one of the returned products - you don't get any results? Could be just lazy loading.

Comment: Have you configured `Lazy loading` as `true` something like that?

Comment: If you are lazy-loading, you will need to visit each record in the result list, and initialise the `person` by using something like `Product.getPersons().size()`

Comment: `OneToMany` relations are lazy by default. If you want the `persons` list to be load eagerly you should put `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` in your `@OneToMany` => `@OneToMany(mappedBy="product", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)`

Comment: Thanks very much to all of you , yes it confirms, EAGER is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have confirmed the problem is with `Lazy loading`, which i already commented, i would like to add it as answer. So that this will be helpful for  people who are coming to this post in future.

You have to configure `lazy loading` in `onetomany` as `false`  using `FetchType.EAGER` as shown below.

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
```

And if you are not specifying this by default lazy loading will be `true`